# Unable to create & sync android project in mac with android studio 3.1.4

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.1.4

Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle
[image]

if I do it in offline mode getting different errors

[image: Could not download kotlin-reflect.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.1.3-2): No cached version available for offline mode]

these are my gradle files tried different build tool versions in last few days but non working please help.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your network is ok?

Comment: yes network is good

Comment: While you are going to build your project, at bottom-right corner a baloon will be opend and ask to agree with terms. You have to click on Agree with terms option and it will start downloading of missing files. That's it.

Comment: Are you behind any firewall?

Comment: I tested connection all Ok. @Henry

Comment: @ParthPatel no bro there's no such popup for terms n all

Comment: I'm using android studio in windows but in Mac unable to build gradle in latest of version of android studio

Comment: @MohammadZahidKhan please go through this: Preference -> Build,Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Android Studio.
then check "Enable embedded Maven repository" option.
then try to build your project.
it will sure ask you in Bubble notification at bottom-right corner of Android Studio.

Comment: @ParthPatel still not working bro, tried it now

Comment: Check, have you set proxy in Android Studio. If set then please set it No Proxy option.